# removing registry key with .reg file

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, regedit

Didnt notice this being asked so here i am.
I have a problem with specific registry key:

```
NvCplDaemon"="RUNDLL32.EXE C:\\Windows\\system32\\NvCpl.dll,NvStartup"
```

Problem is that i have tried many variations of the reg file like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
"NvCplDaemon"=-"RUNDLL32.EXE C:\\Windows\\system32\\NvCpl.dll,NvStartup"
```

and

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"NvCplDaemon"=-"RUNDLL32.EXE C:\\Windows\\system32\\NvCpl.dll,NvStartup"
```

And they all seemingly complete but the key remains.It is not locked or something.I can delete and recreate it manually any time.Im guessing there is some small spelling error on my file because i think i have followed MS instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516

This is how it looks in the registry:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whew.I was finally able to do it.If you watch my previous reply then you notice i have accidental "" in front on NvCplDaemon not one " like it should be.Also i included brackets this time.This is how it looks(and works):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"NvCplDaemon"=-
```

Thank you all for your answers.And indeed its seems like mistake in MS documentation there about not including brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you putting `"RUNDLL32.EXE C:\\Windows\\system32\\NvCpl.dll,NvStartup"` in to the reg file? The documentation says that to remove a value you put a `=-` after the value name.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test
"TestValue"=-
```

Comment: Sorry:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\
"NvCplDaemon"=-

Didnt work

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\
"RUNDLL32.EXE C:\Windows\system32\NvCpl.dll,NvStartup"=-

also didnt work

Comment: You forgot the `[]` around key names.

Comment: The [] are not required here. Read the documentation. TMRW - try removing the trailing \ from "Run".

Comment: Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
""NvCplDaemon"=-


           Still no luck :(